# Classic ASP comparison of comma separated lists

Tags: regex, arrays, asp-classic, vbscript

I have two comma separated lists:-

```
36,189,47,183,65,50

65,50,189,47
```

The question is how to compare the two in classic ASP in order to identify and return any values that exist in list 1 but that don't exist in list 2 bearing in mind that associative arrays aren't available.

E.g., in the above example I would need the return value to be `36,183`

Thanks

Comment: No idea about ASP in particular, but regexes definitely are not suitable for this job.

Comment: Split the strings into arrays and check for array.indexOf or its equivalent. regex is a no-no here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
str1 = "36,189,47,183,65,50"
str2 = "65,50,189,47"

arr1 = Split(str1, ",")
arr2 = Split(str2, ",")

for i = 0 to UBound(arr1)  
   found = false
   for j = 0 to UBound(arr2)
      if arr1(i) = arr2(j) then
         found = true
      end if
   next   
   if found = false then
      Response.Write(arr1(i))
   end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions.  Neither method worked for me. I solved the problem by passing the lists into a SQL stored procedure and populated a couple of temporary tables from which I was able select the unique values and then insert the results into another table.  This was always the end point of the task so it's no great loss to do it in SQL rather than in code and then pass the return values to the DB.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this with regular expression you can use lookaheads (both positive and negative) and references, for example:

```
(zyx:~) % echo '36,189,47,183,65,50;65,50,189,47' | grep -oP '((?>(?<![^,;])[^,;]+))(?=.*;)(?!.*;(|.*,)\1(?=,|$))'
36
183
```

Other variant (works in PCRE but not in perl):

```
(zyx:~) % echo '36,189,47,183,65,50' | grep -oP '((?!(?<=,|^)65|50|189|47(?=,|$))(?<=,|^)[^,]+(?=,|$))'
36
183
```

Have no idea whether any of these works in asp.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript has associative arrays in the form of the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28VS.84%29.aspx) object.

```
Dim list1, list2
list1 = "36,189,47,183,65,50"
list2 = "65,50,189,47"

Dim arr1, arr2
arr1 = Split(list1, ",")
arr2 = Split(list2, ",")

' oDict will hold values from list1
Dim oDict, i
Set oDict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
    oDict(arr1(i)) = 1
Next

' Now loop through list2 and remove matching items from list1
For i = 0 To UBound(arr2)
    If oDict.Exists(arr2(i)) Then
        oDict.Remove arr2(i)
    End If
Next

Response.Write Join(oDict.Keys, ",") ' should be "36,183"
```